# How to totally clear a Gradle dependency (Android app)

Tags: android, gradle

I'm a newbie building an Android application in Android studio. I keep getting this Render error when I try to preview my layout file that looks like it traces back to the RecyclerView widget. I realized I wasn't actually using RecyclerView in my code, so I removed the line `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'` from the dependency section in my `build.gradle`. But after I clean and rebuild and even delete everything from the `.gradle/caches` folder, I'm still getting the error. When I do a search of 'RecyclerView' in my code, I can see that there is still a package `android.support.v7.recyclerview` inside my `app` folder (even though I can't see these files in my actual directories?).

How can I fully get rid of RecyclerView?

Here is the stack trace for the error I'm seeing:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate mode 0  at
>   android.view.DisplayInfo.findMode(DisplayInfo.java:458)   at
>   android.view.DisplayInfo.getMode(DisplayInfo.java:445)    at
>   android.view.Display.getRefreshRate(Display.java:648)     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2392)
>     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15392)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any idea what is going on here?

**EDIT:**
Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.theprotectors.theprotectors"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner             "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
```

To

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

The design library has the recycler view as a dependency. You also have a duplicate AppCompat. Make sure all support library versions are the same.

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have removed recyclerView dependency from `build.gradle` of your app and still you can see the package,

You can try :

**1-**  Go to the  **`app`** folder and navigate to as following given directory: `G:\ABC\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjName\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android. support\recyclerview-v7\` 
from here delete the recyclerView's version.

**2-** From stack trace it is pointing to Rendering issue, so from layout design page instead of picking yourself the Android SDK for rendering choose **`Automatically Pick Best`**

**3-** Clean -> Re-build then Invalidate cache and restart.

**After question edited**

```
compile ('com.android.support:design:+'){
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's still adding RecyclerView version 25.0.0 to my `lib` folder after I do that

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: Just added my build.gradle above